# pass mysql value from node js to angular

Tags: node.js

Hi i have this post function to call create function which will insert to database

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) =>
{
 const body = req.body;
 console.log("tu sam todo_task",req.body);

 try
 {
  const todo_task = await TodoTaskService.create(body);
  console.log(todo_task, "function")

  // created the todo_task! 
  return res.status(201).json({ todo_task: todo_task });
 }
 catch(err)
 {
  
 }
});
```

Then in second snippet i have this create function in service class where i want to return result from mysql query

```js
class TodoTaskService
{
 static create(data)
 {
  console.log("tu sam service todo_task create");
  var vres = todoTaskValidator.validate(data, todo_taskVSchema);
  
  /* validation failed */
  if(!(vres === true))
  {
   let errors = {}, item;

   for(const index in vres)
   {
    item = vres[index];

    errors[item.field] = item.message;
   }
   
   throw {
       name: "ValidationError",
       message: errors
   };
  } 
  console.log("tu sam service todo_task validation passed");
  let todo_task = new TodoTaskModel(data.todo_task_name, data.todo_task_complete_f);



  let connection = mysql.createConnection(dev);

  // insert statment
  let sql = `INSERT INTO todo_task (todo_task_name,todo_task_complete_f) VALUES (?);`
  let values = [data.todo_task_name, data.todo_task_complete_f];


  // execute the insert statment
   connection.query(sql, [values], (err, results, fields) => {
   if (err) {
    global.query = "Database error";
    console.log(err.message + "zasto");
    return err
    
   }
   else{
    // get inserted rows
    global.query = "OK";
    todo_task.todo_task_id = results.insertId
    console.log("rows inserted",todo_task);
    return todo_task;
   }
  }); 
 }

 

 
}
```

How can i pass return todo_task from  connection.query back to the first post function and send it to angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution on my own, don't know how if it's the best practice but here is my solution, I'm using callback to pass the value

```
    router.post('/', async (req, res, next) =>
{
    const body = req.body;
    try
    {
        return await TodoTaskService.create(body,function (result){
            console.log(result, "function result")
            todo_task = result;
            return res.status(201).json({ todo_task: todo_task });
        });


        // created the todo_task! 
        //return res.status(201).json({ todo_task: todo_task });
    }
```

returning callback with result

```
class TodoTaskService
{
    static create(data,callback)
    {
        var vres = todoTaskValidator.validate(data, todo_taskVSchema);

        /* validation failed */
        if(!(vres === true))
        {
            let errors = {}, item;

            for(const index in vres)
            {
                item = vres[index];

                errors[item.field] = item.message;
            }

            throw {
                name: "ValidationError",
                message: errors
            };
        } 
        console.log("tu sam service todo_task validation passed");
        let todo_task = new TodoTaskModel(data.todo_task_name, data.todo_task_complete_f);

        /* todo_task.uid = 'c' + counter++;

        todo_tasks[todo_task.uid] = todo_task; */

        let connection = mysql.createConnection(dev);

        // insert statment
        let sql = `INSERT INTO todo_task (todo_task_name,todo_task_complete_f) VALUES (?);`
        let values = [data.todo_task_name, data.todo_task_complete_f];


        // execute the insert statment
        connection.query(sql, [values], (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                global.query = "Database error";
                console.log(err.message + "zasto");
                return err

            }
            else{
                // get inserted rows
                global.query = "OK";
                todo_task.todo_task_id = results.insertId
                console.log("rows inserted",todo_task);
                return callback(todo_task);
            }
        }); 
    }
```